# How to match multiple patterns on single EPL query

Tags: esper

I have two different match recognize patterns created in Esper event processing language, when I run these one by one they are working fine but I need to get result from both of these patterns on incoming events. The patterns are defined as below.

(1)

```
match_recognize( "
measures A as a, B as b "
pattern (A B) "
define "
A as A.scene= 'stock'and A.activity='assembly' and A.task='picking' and A.mod2='FT' and A.mod3='Scn', 
B as B.scene='stock' and B.activity='assembly' and B.task='picking' and B.mod2='PG' and B.mod3='GzS')
```

(2)

```
match_recognize( 
measures A as a, B as b, C as c 
pattern (A B C) 
define
A as A.scene= 'assembly'and A.activity='assembly' and A.task='moving' and A.mod2='GrS' and A.mod3='GzS', 
B as B.scene='assembly' and B.activity='assembly' and B.task='moving' and B.mod2='GrT' and B.mod3='Follow', 
C as C.scene='assembly' and C.activity='assembly' and C.task='moving' and C.mod2='GrT' and C.mod3='GzS')
```

I need to get result when any one of these patterns is matched with incoming events on a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so what is the problem? You simple create them both and add a listener to each and its all done.

First example:

```
String epl = "@name('first') select ... from ...;\n";
epl += "@name('second') select ... from ...;\n";
epAdministrator.getDeploymentAdmin().parseDeploy(epl);
epAdministrator.getStatement('first').addListener(new MyListener());
epAdministrator.getStatement('second').addListener(new MyListener());
```

Another example:

```
EPStatement first = epAdministrator.createEPL(...);
first.addListener(new MyUpdateListener());
EPStatement second = epAdministrator.createEPL(...);
second.addListener(new MyUpdateListener());
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i need to match four patterns, i have created epl query: select * from StateVector#length_batch(500) but i have four patterns that i want to match after this query, when anyone of these is matched then the listener should be invoked?

Comment: i am very new in Esper, if i create both then how to add listener to each?

Comment: thank you very much for your help but i think in this way i will have to repeat select statements again and again, is there no anyway that i use one select statement and match multiple patterns because i am fetching data from only one file. thanks